# Cannot build .NET Framework web app targeting 4.7.2 with VS 2022 installed on a docker container

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, visual-studio, azure-pipelines

I can't successfully build basic ASP.NET web app targeting framework 4.7.2.
I built a docker image with a base image for [Windows Server Core 2019](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore). On this image I installed [VS 2022 Enterprise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise?view=vs-2022) and took Azure development, .NET desktop development, ASP.NET and web development modules, including recommended ones.
For dotnet core solutions everything works fine, but for dotnet framework I am getting such errors:

```
packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\build\net46\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props(31,5): Error MSB3758: An error has occurred during compilation. error CS0014: Required file 'alink.dll' could not be found

packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\build\net46\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props(31,5): Error MSB4175: The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" could not be loaded from the assembly "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll". The task factory must return a value for the "TaskType" property.
```

I additionally installed .NET Frameworks: 4.5, 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.7.1, 4.8, but it didn't help.
Locally, I am able to build it without any problems. I checked the image if VS 2022 was installed without any issues and it looks fine as well. All environment variables are also in place. I thought the issue was related with some missing .NET Frameworks with SDKs, but it still persists.

Installing Redistributable C++ 2012-2022 didn't help as well. I am using MSBuild 17.
What I still might be missing?

I want to create an agent for Azure DevOps and as a reference I use [the Dockerfile from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops#create-and-build-the-dockerfile) documentation. One difference is that before the start script, I run my custom script to silently install the VS 2022 with the modules I specified earlier.
I use Azure DevOps pipelines to build the solution, and the [VSBuild@1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build?view=azure-devops) task.

Comment: What's the issue your are facing while you build on the docker? How's the dockerfile look like?

Comment: Did you install the runtimes or the sdks?

Comment: I added an update for a better context. I have installed all sdks with targeting packs: 4.5, 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.7.1, 4.7.2, 4.8. From VS, 4.8 runtime installed

Comment: I assume something else might be missing. Please notice that I start from base win server core and I install most of the tools from VS installer. The issue is I can't build asp.net basic web apps because I receive the error with missing `alink.dll` or assembiles from `Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll`

Comment: Why did you install Visual Studio in the Docker image? That really shouldn't be necessary.  Nor should installing C++ components. Just put the build artifacts (DLL's, CSS, JS, etc) in the image. And start with the correct base image. Windows Server Core would be a pretty barebones one. For an ASP.NET app, you need one with IIS and .NET framework already installed. Use [mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-aspnet).

Comment: If you want to build in a container so you don't have to have VS on the host machine, then you can use [this image](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-sdk/). You'd want to do a two-step thing, where you build the app in the first container (the sdk container) and then copy the build artifacts out of that container and into the 2nd container (the aspnet container).

Comment: I don't want to host a single application on a docker container. I need to have an image with tools to build many applications using that container. Everything works except .Net Framework build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to solve the problem I had. It turned out that the base `windows server core` image didn't contain all of the needed prerequisites nor Visual Studio. Solution was to use extended `windows server core` image with `sdk 4.8`. This is strange, because Visual Studio already delivers everything for sdk 4.8. I think the extended image must have had something else that didn't come with the VS installation.

Comment: Had the same issue, and the base image with 4.8 SDK fixed it for me too.

Comment: Hi, Can you please share the command to use extended windows server core image with sdk 4.7.2. Thanks !